# what is the SI value in powershell ps?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, ps

I am trying to find process execution information with powershell ps. 
There is an attribute 'SI' whose values are usually like 0, 2, 10, etc. 
Specifically, I typed in the following to powershell:

```
    PS C:\Users\> ps -pid 10860

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                  
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                  
    175      12    23068      12276       0.20  10860   2 geckodriver
```

Thanks!
There is no code.
I could not find documentation for this SI attribute. 
Can anyone help ? 
Thanks

Comment: Post your code and output.

Comment: Thanks!
There is no code.  
Just a command line to powershell as follows. 
PS C:\Users\> ps -pid 10860

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                  
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                  
    175      12    23068      12276       0.20  10860   2 geckodriver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Session ID](https://brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops). Session 0 is shown for all services, Session 1 for first logged on user and 2 because you switch from user 1 to a new user logon.

I only have 1 user on my Tablet and so it shows session 0 for services and 1 for my user programs.

```
PS C:\Users\Andre> ps

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                       
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                       
    655      20    22852      25232      13,47   7476   1 ApplicationFrameHost                                                                              
    178       6     6564      11284     301,89   7360   0 audiodg                                                                                           
    299       8     3104       6828       6,72   1688   1 CastSrv                                                                                           
    277      14    28772      43276      11,34   1444   1 chrome                                                                                            
    196       6     1500       7604       0,11   2616   1 chrome                                                                                            
    315      16    48092      70208      35,52   5344   1 chrome                                                                                            
    284      13    24300      38344      16,03   8636   1 chrome                                                                                            
    485      15    33988      45832       6,41  10772   1 chrome                                                                                            
   1359      30    43184      84848     113,13  12620   1 chrome                                                                                            
    272      13    29400      42300      68,94  12740   1 chrome                                                                                            
    143       6     1424       8264       0,09  13524   1 chrome                                                                                            
    236       8     5376      12480       0,63  14008   1 chrome                                                                                            
     42       2     1840       2492       0,05   9964   1 cmd                                                                                               
    106       3      868       4808       0,06   2784   0 conhost                                                                                           
    302       8     3924      15772       1,91   6948   1 conhost                                                                                           
    136       5     6196      10668       0,11   9296   1 conhost                                                                                           
    401       8     1076       3904      10,25    580   0 csrss                                                                                             
    623      13     1356       4744     208,95    676   1 csrss                                                                                             
    461      10     4044      24312      32,73   6220   1 ctfmon                                                                                            
    743      13     9928      19712      98,80   1716   0 dasHost                                                                                           
    310       8     3316      13848      27,05   3104   1 dllhost                                                                                           
    323      15     5564      11112       2,03   7840   1 dllhost                                                                                           
     76       3      748       1212       0,08   3436   0 DptfParticipantDisplayService                                                                     
     73       3      732       3640       0,06   3332   0 DptfParticipantProcessorService                                                                   
     73       3      772       3628       0,08   3316   0 DptfPolicyCriticalService                                                                         
     77       3      776       1180       0,02   3356   0 DptfPolicyLpmService                                                                              
     59       3      612       1888       0,08   5828   1 DptfPolicyLpmServiceHelper                                                                        
   1218      25    34116      32620   4.721,06   1208   1 dwm                                                                                               
    147       6     1204       5800     159,03   3324   0 Everything                                                                                        
   2752      52    58652      73936   7.344,41   5884   1 explorer                                                                                          
    787      23    13508      37132     327,50  11268   1 fdm                                                                                               
     76       3      736       4528       0,03  11028   1 fdm_nativehost                                                                                    
     45       3     1164       2944       0,28    948   0 fontdrvhost                                                                                       
     68       5     3052       9076     120,55    952   1 fontdrvhost                                                                                       
    369      15    10576       8452       4,58   4936   1 HideVolumeOSD                                                                                     
      0       0       24          4                 0   0 Idle                                                                                              
    174       5     1428       7228       0,30   1844   0 igfxCUIService                                                                                    
    273       8     6960       5340       1,69   6080   1 igfxEM                                                                                            
    140       6     5276       2836       0,53   6096   1 igfxHK                                                                                            
    488      14    13080      21368       5,77    940   1 LockApp                                                                                           
   1319      14     5900      13644     175,31    816   0 lsass                                                                                             
      0       0      740      85616     854,14    972   0 Memory Compression                                                                                
    161       6     1576       6184       0,52   7660   1 MSASCuiL                                                                                          
    840      37   157044      94148   1.988,09   3564   0 MsMpEng                                                                                           
    457      17    16292      10744       0,91   7348   1 Music.UI                                                                                          
    206       8     9020       9028       6,78   4408   0 NisSrv                                                                                            
    108       4     2320       5072       0,25   3396   0 nsmservice                                                                                        
    768      25    41364      33948     153,39   5848   1 OneDrive                                                                                          
    726      25    35836      54688      11,09  12892   1 powershell                                                                                        
    282       9     2736       4128       1,13   4204   1 ReflectUI                                                                                         
    347      10     5584      17088      20,16    924   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    457      13     6460      20444      42,02   3444   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    722      18    10564      24836     131,80   4792   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    225       8     2512      13452       0,72   4980   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    331       9     5716      15136      11,78   8424   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    101       4     1168       5648       0,16   9288   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
    551      14     9996      28948     444,34  12184   1 RuntimeBroker                                                                                     
   1062      33    27444      35180      70,03  10516   1 salamand                                                                                          
    112       4      940       4732       0,05   9684   1 salmon                                                                                            
    885      39    42164      46048     169,41   6228   0 SearchIndexer                                                                                     
   1346      49    78356      65452      62,16   1236   1 SearchUI                                                                                          
    375       9     3720       9240      47,39   3484   0 SecurityHealthService                                                                             
    380       6     3452       6604      99,70    804   0 services                                                                                          
    705      25    40724      19376     454,56   6496   1 SettingSyncHost                                                                                   
    828      20    21552      38476       5,41  13712   1 ShellExperienceHost                                                                               
    789      13     8308      23400     180,23   5292   1 sihost                                                                                            
    238      10    10304      16060       0,34  11748   1 smartscreen                                                                                       
     52       2      308        816       0,34    360   0 smss                                                                                              
    405      12     4128      10400       2,06   2508   0 spoolsv                                                                                           
   1014      16    16228      24620     369,30    932   0 svchost                                                                                           
   1012      13     8156      13052     806,22   1112   0 svchost                                                                                           
    814      34    20012      30936   1.551,09   1312   0 svchost                                                                                           
   1338      57    18068      33312     559,58   1320   0 svchost                                                                                           
    862      21     8832      16132     319,78   1380   0 svchost                                                                                           
    868      16    17260      19900     205,52   1400   0 svchost                                                                                           
    464      11     3528      11364     111,23   1408   0 svchost                                                                                           
   1011      25     9216      20868     431,77   1832   0 svchost                                                                                           
    550      16     4648      12380     309,44   1856   0 svchost                                                                                           
   4465      43    27908      42332     765,88   1940   0 svchost                                                                                           
    289       7     2252      10368      11,94   2120   0 svchost                                                                                           
    133       6     1372       5492      25,08   2248   0 svchost                                                                                           
    390      12     4244      12172     265,75   2344   0 svchost                                                                                           
    557       7     5744      15192     435,09   2416   0 svchost                                                                                           
    198       7     5312      13272       6,75   2472   0 svchost                                                                                           
    504      13     8852      21628      47,73   3304   0 svchost                                                                                           
    767      48    57844      28896     954,86   3692   0 svchost                                                                                           
   1061      28    16724      41412     328,97   5300   1 svchost                                                                                           
    212       6     2000       5440       1,70   7044   0 svchost                                                                                           
    193       7     1468       5084       7,16   7624   0 svchost                                                                                           
    222       8     3176      12156       0,19   8180   0 svchost                                                                                           
    581      10     4756      14312      21,38   8704   0 svchost                                                                                           
   3714       0       52         64   5.555,03      4   0 System                                                                                            
    776      22    15532      11556       1,52   6124   1 SystemSettings                                                                                    
    242       8     2600      10108       0,23  10140   1 SystemSettingsAdminFlows                                                                          
    397      12     4024      11748      23,94   6248   1 TabTip                                                                                            
    301      19     8072      11384      35,81   5396   1 taskhostw                                                                                         
    303      10     4624      13108      21,58  11364   1 taskhostw                                                                                         
    679      18    18580      41008      23,41  11636   1 Taskmgr                                                                                           
    487      15    12428       7032       1,02   9864   1 Time                                                                                              
    215       8     4964       1696      12,77   5640   1 TouchMousePointer                                                                                 
    140       5     1300       6424       3,64   3608   1 TouchZoomDesktopCore                                                                              
     61       3      616       1084       0,02   3516   0 TouchZoomDesktopService                                                                           
    113       4     1044       1268       0,13   8384   1 TouchZoomDesktopTray                                                                              
    370      40    21144      16500      65,39   4836   1 USBSafelyRemove                                                                                   
    141       4     2324       5476       0,19    328   0 USBSRService                                                                                      
    559      15    14612      27976      16,61   7788   1 WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp                                    
    145       6      960       4856       0,23    660   0 wininit                                                                                           
    254       6     2060       7684       0,98    764   1 winlogon                                                                                          
   1004      32    43204       7980       5,61   4604   1 WinStore.App                                                                                      
    155       5     1996       6760      19,27   2756   0 wlanext                                                                                           
    154       5     2008       7448       0,09   3068   0 WmiPrvSE                                                                                          
    582      10     4880      11352   1.083,78   1020   0 WUDFHost                                                                                          
    381      12    28564      15868       0,81   4576   1 XboxApp
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there a way to know whether the processes are ready, running, sleep, zombie, etc., like in the ps of linux ?

Comment: ps | Format-List *    - this shows detailed data. Responding shows you true for running and false for suspended processes.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `PS|Get-Member` you'll see:

```
   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name                       MemberType     Definition
----                       ----------     ----------
Handles                    AliasProperty  Handles = Handlecount
Name                       AliasProperty  Name = ProcessName
NPM                        AliasProperty  NPM = NonpagedSystemMemorySize64
PM                         AliasProperty  PM = PagedMemorySize64
SI                         AliasProperty  SI = SessionId
VM                         AliasProperty  VM = VirtualMemorySize64
WS                         AliasProperty  WS = WorkingSet64

...
```

So `SI` is an abbreviation for `SessionID`

Comment: Provided output comes from `PS|Get-Member -MemberType AliasProperty`.

Comment: @JosefZ In fact it was the complete output but snipped after the AliasProperties. The `...`should denote that. The result is obviously the same.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to know whether the processes are ready, running, sleep, etc., like the ps in linux ?

Comment: Take a look at **ALL** properties and methods with an uncut `ps|gm` or `ps powershell|fl *`